# Converting timestamp to xml

Tags: sql-server, xml, timestamp

It is possible to do the following:

```
SELECT SomeTimestampColumn FROM SomeTable FOR XML PATH('')
```

and the result looks like a string
e.g.

```
<SomeTimestampColumn >AAAAAATJ2y4=</SomeTimestampColumn>
```

But for some reason, SQL doesn't allow me to do this

SELECT CONVERT(xml,SomeTimestampColumn) FROM SomeTable

There are two related questions here:

1. Is there some other way (besides XML PATH('')) to get the equivalent string from sql or
2. Is there a better way of capturing/converting that timestamp into a more manipulable string (I need to pass this back and forth between a c# application and will be using it to determine that no-one else has altered the row in the meantime)

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @T table(SomeTimestampColumn timestamp, id int)

insert into @T(id) values(1)
insert into @T(id) values(2)

select 
  (select SomeTimestampColumn for xml path('')) as SomeTimestampColumn
from @T
```

If you want the column to be XML type

```
select 
  (select SomeTimestampColumn for xml path(''), type) as SomeTimestampColumn
from @T
```

Or if you only want the value

```
select
  T1.ID,
  T3.N.value('.', 'varchar(50)') as SomeTimestampColumn
from @T as T1
  cross apply
    (select T1.SomeTimestampColumn for xml path(''), type) as T2(X)
  cross apply
    T2.X.nodes('SomeTimestampColumn') as T3(N)
```

Result

```
ID          SomeTimestampColumn
----------- --------------------------------------------------
1           AAAAAAACDZg=
2           AAAAAAACDZk=
```

The conversion is to Base64 and you can convert it back. Here is a link to some UDF's that can do the conversion as well. http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=554886

```
declare @T table(SomeTimestampColumn timestamp, id int)

insert into @T(id) values(1)

declare @Base64 varchar(max)
declare @Binary varbinary(max)

select
  @Binary = T1.SomeTimestampColumn,
  @Base64 = T3.N.value('.', 'varchar(50)')
from @T as T1
  cross apply
    (select T1.SomeTimestampColumn for xml path(''), type) as T2(X)
  cross apply
    T2.X.nodes('SomeTimestampColumn') as T3(N)

select
  @Base64,
  CAST(N'' AS XML).value('xs:base64Binary(xs:hexBinary(sql:variable("@Binary")))', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'),
  @Binary,
  CAST(N'' AS XML).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:variable("@Base64"))', 'VARBINARY(MAX)')
```

Result:

```
AAAAAAAAJ3k=    AAAAAAAAJ3k=    0x0000000000002779  0x0000000000002779
```

Comment: All good snippets, thanks, testing each now to see what works best.

Comment: Do you have any idea what it is doing to the timestamp type to mangle it into XML ? My only worry is that this seems to be a one-way conversion (converting back to Binary(8) seems to produce garbage) and I don't know for sure if it will always generate unique string rows?

Comment: @Runonthespot - It is converted to base64 and can be converted back to binary again.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want to do:

```
SELECT convert(datetime, SomeTimestampColumn) 
FROM SomeTable FOR XML PATH('SomeTimestampColumn')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's specifically the "timestamp" datatype which isn't datetime - it's basically an internal datatype that can only be converted to binary(8) and I can't work out how to predictably convert it into something string-like for xml.